# Sell banner ad space functionality

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a site in asp.net MVC3.
Clients wants to be able to sell banner ad space on his site (somewhere in the footer 3 banners would show up). I need some feedback as far as the functionality goes. Would he be charging per impression? or click? or both? or a flat rate?. what are some solutions you guys have implemented in the past?

thanks.
Shane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already implemented charging per click and also flat rate. both will work fine. never tested impression because it works like flat rate.

both of my implemented plans works because each user has different thing in his mind and wants us to service as he/she likes. you can have these to plans together. as I did it and was helpful.